# Asymptotic analysis - Regular perturbations in ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm hoping to get some help answering the following question. I've seen it asked before, but I sadly didn't understand any of the responses.

> Find the first two terms in an asymptotic expansion in powers of the small
> parameter ε of the solution of:

> $$  xy'(x) + y(x) = ε(y(x))^\frac 12, x > 1, y(1) = 1 $$

Here's what I've done so far:

Letting ε = 0, we obtain $$ xy'(x) + y(x) = 0 $$

hence $$ y(x) = \frac cx $$

c constant.

Using y(1) = 1, we get $$ y(x) = \frac 1x $$

Now I assume a better approximation of the form $$ y(x) = \frac 1x + εy_0(x) + ε^2y_1(x) + O(ε^3) $$

I can differentiate this to get $$ y'(x) = -(\frac 1x)^2 + εy_0'(x) + ε^2y_1'(x) + O(ε^3) $$

In other examples, I have then gone on to plug y(x) and y'(x) into the original ODE, then equate the coefficients of each power of ε to find y0 and y1, but I'm not sure how to deal with the square root on the RHS of the ODE.

i.e. how do I write the RHS as a polynomial in ε?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Factor out $\sqrt{1/x}$ from it. What remains is of the form $\sqrt{1+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)}$. For this factor, apply the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+w}$ about $w=0$. See if this leads to anywhere.

Comment: Even if you do need three terms, which is not how I would read this prompt, it is easier to look at if you work one term at a time. You have the first term already. For the second term, you want to have $x(x^{-1})' + \varepsilon x y_0' + (x^{-1}) + \varepsilon y_0 = \varepsilon (x^{-1}+\varepsilon y_0)^{1/2} + o(\varepsilon)$. This can be achieved by Taylor expanding the nonlinear term and discarding the order $\varepsilon^2$ term.

Comment: Set $y=z^2$, then either $z=0$ or $2xz'+z=ε$, which is separable. Or solve as first-order linear equation. $z=ε+cx^{-1/2}$, $c=1-ε$. Now square this...

Comment: @Gary Thank you, I've sorted it now!